# High Performance Video File Server In NodeJS

Tags: node.js, video, video-streaming

I would like to build a high availability and high performance video file server and streaming video in NodeJS. Basically, I wanted to know:

1. What are the possible ways to create video file server in NodeJS.
2. Will it manage many concurrent requests. Since this is a video file, each request is taking time to resolve completely.
3. Are there any other possibilities to use another static file server.

Please suggest to me how to get on the right path.

Comment: Nginx is a performant web server that also has some modules for streaming.

Comment: @aergistal, In stream, I wanted to upload video files as well. Please give more info on how about Nginx handle these more concurrent requests.

Comment: Nginx uses multiple worker threads (eg. one per CPU core) and each worker threads handles multiple connections (default 512). This is handled using the reactor pattern which offers high-performance I/O. You should rather start with the hardware/bandwidth requirements.

Comment: @aergistal  Thanks, Can I reset thread limit? If yes, what would be the maximum value. Where can I find all these information?

Comment: This blog gives me some information https://www.nginx.com/blog/thread-pools-boost-performance-9x/

Comment: I agree with aergistal Nginx is a perfomant web server and a load balancer. but there are many ways to achieve that, With NodeJS u may use BinaryJS. @hilarudeens

Comment: What's the end user? What are you streaming to?

Comment: @Profstyle, I have gone through BinaryJS. It looks good. However, It is working on the top of Socket connection. If I want to stream video to HTML5 video tag, I have to build data url which is require to download entire video content/data. This will lead user to wait.

Comment: @Alex, Sorry, please elaborate what do you want to understand?

Comment: Where are you streaming to? mobile device? web app? HTML5 app

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Alex, This is both mobile and web. However, I am focusing mobile as of now.

Comment: @Anatoly, I have managed by modifying some part in video https://github.com/meloncholy/vid-streamer. Is there any better solution?

Comment: @hilarudeens yes, there is my answer below

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Video streaming is about mostly efficient data transfer via HTTP(s). Data is your files, data transfer via webserver may have nothing shared with NodeJS or any kind of backend processing. It depends on requirements but data as files usually served directly to the users without passing them through backend. Otherwise the system elements become to coupled together which affect performance and increases entropy.

It is recommended to keep system parts separately, for instance Nginx can handle authentication, authorization, video streaming all in once without any backend which can be a good starting point and definitely real high performant. Check [this approach](https://gist.github.com/mikhailov/3174601) out:

```
server {
   location /video/ {
      rewrite               /video/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)\.flv$ /flv/$3.mp4?st=$1&e=$2;
    }

    location /mp4/ {
      internal;
      mp4;
      secure_link           $arg_st,$arg_e;
      secure_link_md5       YOUR_SECRET_PASSWORD_HERE$arg_e$uri;
}
```

The URL for video file will be pregenerated by backend based on a certain algorithm, in the example it's done via Ruby but there is [an example on Bash](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html):

```
echo -n '2147483647/s/link127.0.0.1 secret' | \
    openssl md5 -binary | openssl base64 | tr +/ -_ | tr -d =
```

Once you reach this primary goal (video files streaming?) then NodeJS or any other given technology can be used for common tasks like enhanced authentication, authorization, commenting, sharing and other functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments there are other out of the box options to have a video streaming server available ([ngix](https://www.nginx.com/products/streaming-media-delivery/) module seems to be quite appropriate). Nevertheless if you still want to build your own, using [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) the right tool for the job seems to be [BinaryJS](http://binaryjs.com/). Has quite a straight forward way of developing it:

*server*

```
var server = BinaryServer({port: 9000});
server.on('connection', function(client){
client.on('stream', function(stream, meta){
     var file = fs.createWriteStream(meta.file);
     stream.pipe(file);
   }); 
});
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/blob/master/doc/start.md) and [demo](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/tree/master/examples) section is quite nicely documented, and easy to use.

Comment: The issue is following code part, `client.on('stream', function(stream, meta){    
    var parts = []; 
    stream.on('data', function(data){
      parts.push(data); // Push all data packets in array. Because of this user has to wait to load all the data.(In HTML5 Video Tag)
    });
    stream.on('end', function(){
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(new Blob(parts));
      document.body.appendChild(img);
    });
});`.

Comment: @hilarudeens which one?

Comment: @hilarudeens - what's the issue?

Comment: `createObjectURL(new Blob(parts))` To generate Blob instance, I have to get all data chunks from the server. Let's assume, I have a video file with 500MB of size. Hence, the user has to wait to load all video and then the video is getting start to play. I guess, you are in 4G. You can feel the delay in 3G. This is the issue. I can't go with BinaryJs.

Comment: @hilarudeens from what I can see, BinaryServer() has the chunckSize parameter (defaults to 40960) that points the size of the chuck to send. Wouldn't this suffice?

Answer (score -1):

A lot of the comments are good suggestions.  The biggest bottleneck is going to be the file server, both in terms of performance and scalability.  My suggestion would be to use Couchbase.  It is the highest performing database due to its caching methods, and is able to add nodes to clusters dynamically.  Before taking my word on this do some research, because what id does is sort of "shoot first ask questions later".  It will store the data received in RAM, report success, then write to disk later.  Similarly it will keep frequently accessed files stored in RAM, which will help performance greatly if multiple users are watching the same video.  When a node is added to the cluster it announces itself and its peers automatically start sending it data to balance loads.  Load balancing happens automatically as well.

http://www.couchbase.com/

As for the web server use whatever's comfortable.  Nginx would be good, NodeJS is set up for things like Couchbase, and Apache and even IIS would work.  Choose what language you want to work in first, then pick a server based on those options.

Lastly you might check into pre-existing server-side video streaming code libraries.  You could save a lot of headache doing that.